# mysql count not retning value

Tags: mysql, count

Im having trouble counting the number of rows.

Here's my query

```
$categoryEntries = mysql_result(
             mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(cat_id) 
                         FROM directory_listings 
                         WHERE cat_id = 3 
                         AND WHERE status = 'approved'"));
```

but when I echo $categoryEntries it appears empty

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: statement is wrong
printing result is wrong
using mysql (deprecated extension) is wrong

Answer (score 0):

why not use this

```
$categoryEntries  = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(cat_id) as counts FROM directory_listings WHERE cat_id = 3 AND  status = 'approved'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($categoryEntries);
echo $row['counts'];
```

changed this

```
  AND WHERE status = 'approved'
```

to

```
 AND  status = 'approved'
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_result` expects two parameters. The second is the row number (which should be `0` in this case).

Apart from that, you are not checking the result of the `mysql_query` function, so you don't catch any problems in case anything goes wrong. In this case the query is wrong (the second occurrence of the keyword `WHERE` is invalid), which you would have caught with better checking of the result values.

And of course the `mysql` library is deprecated, as you would have read if you had checked the documentation of the functions before asking this question: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the end.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT count(cat_id) AS total from directory_listings WHERE cat_id = 3 AND status = 'approved'");
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$count = $data['total'];
```